# Angularjs routing with multiple modules

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on a angularjs application with multiple modules. Every module has its own template and controller.
Let's say appModule, contactModule and aboutModule.

I am currently using ng-switch based on the url to navigate between screens. The problem is that every time is switch between the screen my controller is re-initialized and is making service calls to get the data. I only want to get the data first time I go that screen.

Basically, I would like to know if I am in the right path or is there a better way to do this using routeProvider?

Comment: I assume you mean you don't want to go to the backend for the data more than once.  In that case, you can save the data in an angular service, and each time the controller is initialized, you can call the service to see if the data exists, and if so, then return it, and if not, then you can fetch the data from the backend, and save it in the service.

Comment: Actually, its not that i don't want to go to the backend to get the data more than once . I also want to restore the state of the screen when the user comes back to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this problem:

1. Use $resource and http-cache to cache get request.
2. Delegate the the fetching of data to a service or factory, and store the response in that service, inject it to the controller and databind to the property with the stored response.
3. Use ng-show/ng-hide instead of switch so the controller remains instantiated.
4. Use sticky states with ui-router exras https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home

Comment: Is using ng-switch the right approach? or should i be using ngRoute?

Comment: If you want to navigate between routes you should use ngRoute, i.e. `myapp.com/contacts` and `myapp.com/about`. But that alone wont solve the controllers getting reinstantiated and re-fetching data.

Comment: You are right, I changes my logic to use ngRoute. It still does not solve the problem. Issue is not just with getting the data. When i enter some text in a TextBox, if i move out of the tab and come back again. The entered text is disappeared. I guess my question should have been, how can i maintain the state while navigating between screen.

Comment: Then I suggest you use sticky states with ui-router and ui-router-extras modules. http://plnkr.co/edit/bFMLqLENmPFfCD0XCz8V?p=preview